# HP ProLiant DL360 G5 issue while booting (no error messages, just beep code)

Tags: hp-proliant, boot

I need helps as I cannot boot up the server. There are 2 processes happen:

- 1st: The server checks for hardware issue but since no beeps, I guess everything is ok. The monitor is white (slowly blinking) then black out.
- 2nd: The server tries to boot but finds out some issues, it starts beeping while the white screen is slowly blinking (looks like the previous process). The beep audible is: 6 short -- 2 long -- 2 short. Few seconds later, the server stop booting (shutdown).

NOTE:

- The top led is red as seen in very first few second of the video (and it stays red whole time)
- I check all 9 fans (3 units = 9 fans) all are running and produce strong wind

I recorded a video with detailed annotations: https://youtu.be/Y3Z7uEAt0VQ

Any helps are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to the ILO2 interface and read the contents of the IML log.

It will tell you exactly why the server is complaining.

Comment: I don't remember if I have ILO enabled. If you take a quick look of the video, the server cannot start. Is there still a way to connect to ILO? Thanks!