# HP ProLiant DL360 G5 gets stuck at blank white screen (no beeps, no errors)

Tags: hp-proliant, boot, bare-metal

A few days ago, my server (Linux CoreOS) start running incredible slow with lots of failed services.

**Try #1:**
- I thought it was an OS issue so I decided to reinstall my Linux then I found out there is 1 (of 3) drive in my RAID5 failed. 
- When I plug my monitor into the server, it was just a blinking white screen while booting and non-blinking white screen after that.
- The IML log in iLO2 just keep displaying 1 drive failed & rebuilding the RAID5 array.

**Try #2:**
- I bought a completely new 6 drives and replace all the 3 existing drives with those new ones. However there are only 4 (of 6) drives got green leds, the remaining 2 have no led at all (event at the very beginning all 6 drives have leds)
- After some reboots, the symptom (on the monitor) is exactly as #1.

***==== Then I record this video: https://youtu.be/eVX_CHn1kYU ====***

(I show the mainboard leds & switches as well)

**Try #3:**
- I removed all RAM, the health check start showing error (in server health board & IML log) immediately.

**UPDATE #1**

System's health status
[image: System's health status]

IML logs
[image: IML logs]

**UPDATE #2** Sorry, I'm really a newbie to this as I'm a software developer. I'm just starting to learn about server management. Also I'm in Singapore, not in US, and it's not easy to buy a server.

1. I don't have any KVM switch, just simply a bare metal server I bought & place at my house for learning & personal usage. I plug monitor & keyboard directly to the server
2. I tried both front & rear video output, the results are the same.
3. I install ILO Advanced license & see the same thing from the remote console:

   - While booting the screen keep blinking (same as external monitor as seen in the YouTube-uploaded video)
   - After booted, the whole screen is completely white (same as external monitor)
4. I tried to turn On & Off the ILO Security switch but no changes to server (of course I will have to login to ILO if it's On)

Remote Console from iLO2 - The screen and the cursor keep blinking
[image: Remote Console from iLO2 - The screen and the cursor keep blinking]

Remote Serial Console from iLO2 - The screen is not interactive (not responding)
[image: Remote Serial Console from iLO2 - The screen is not interactive (not responding)]

Answer (score 1):

You may have a failed/failing system board.

Can you post the details of the IML log here? 

Also, what is the system status in the ILO?

If your monitor is a problem, try using the ILO's interface to view the system boot.

---

Edit:

So I don't want to get into the detailed steps of teaching people how to deal with hardware or build servers because there's a lot to cover.

- Please troubleshoot and see if you can find another monitor or check connections.
- If you have a KVM switch, [please remove it](https://serverfault.com/a/466340/13325) and connect monitor and keyboard directly to the server.
- The server has VGA monitor ports on the front *and* rear of the chassis. Try both.
- You don't have an ILO Advanced Key. Search the underbelly of the internet for one or [sign up for a trial from HPE](https://h20392.www2.hpe.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=ILO_TRIALS).
- The ILO Advanced key will allow you to view the screen of the server.
- The ILO security switch is set on your server. Please put it back.

*If you can get the machine running:*

- Set the clock in the BIOS.
- Update the firmware.
- You need to configure your Smart Array controller and logical drives in order for them to light up. That can be done in the BIOS, but you need to be able to view the server's monitor.

If all else fails, this is a 10 year-old server, and there's only so much you can do. It looks like [you've had problems](https://serverfault.com/questions/778752/hp-proliant-dl360-g5-issue-while-booting-no-error-messages-just-beep-code) with this server before in the recent past. The [street value is very low](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=dl360%20g5&_sop=15&LH_BIN=1&_osacat=175700&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.X1u%20dl360%20g5.TRS1&_nkw=1u%20dl360%20g5&_sacat=175700) and there are few support options available right now.

Comment: I updated (#1) the question with images. I tried Remote Console in iLO but all throw some Java errors and can't show anything from server.

Comment: I do appreciate your kind help! I followed your instruction & updated (#2). Basically the symptom from remote console is the same with external monitor.

Comment: I think the video chip died. A long time ago i had server with the same trouble and it works more 2 years. To configure RAID you can use console command. But don't use this server as storage for important data. Change motherboard or make backup more often.

Comment: G5 servers are ancient now, I bet you could buy  a G8 or G9 for a few hundred bucks.  As to your comment about the remote console / java not working, that is typical for servers of this age. The Java release when G5 was around was probably 5 or 6.  we're on 8 now.  You can get old java versions from the java archive, but due to some glaring security issues, you can't reliably use them on newer windows.  I've had luck with spinning up a WinXP VM for this purpose, but my best advice is just get a new server to tinker with.  Send this one home.